# gradle liberty No such property: outputDir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: gradle, open-liberty

Error to execute task libertyDev using gradle-3.2.1.

Execution failed for task ':libertyDev'.

> No such property: outputDir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

IF I switch to gradle-6.4.1 I get a different error.
hanym@LAPTOP-EQC0BINN MINGW64 ~/liberty/demo-devmode (master)
$ gradle libertyDev
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :libertyDev FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':libertyDev'.

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

hanym@LAPTOP-EQC0BINN MINGW64 ~/liberty/demo-devmode (master)

hanym@LAPTOP-EQC0BINN MINGW64 ~/liberty/demo-devmode (master)
$ gradle --version

---

### Gradle 6.4.1

Build time:   2020-05-15 19:43:40 UTC
Revision:     1a04183c502614b5c80e33d603074e0b4a2777c5

Kotlin:       1.3.71
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Eclipse OpenJ9 openj9-0.20.0)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: hi, can you include more details, such as the contents of your build.gradle file? There isn't enough info to determine what's wrong currently

Comment: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/demo-devmode

Comment: looks like it might be a bug in the gradle plugin. Can you raise an issue on github here please? https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.gradle
Also please include what OS and terminal you are using (looks like cygwin perhaps?)